# Shorten MVC Controller Route Uri

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have a default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Structures",
    url: "Structures/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Structures", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works great, just what I wanted it to do.  So it looks like I can manually change the url parameter to whatever pattern I want.  So why then, does this not work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Structures",
    url: "s/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Structures", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I know that the asp.net default routing uses the {name}Controller pattern and extracts {name} and uses it as the Url but it doesn't seem to work if I want to customize the portion of the url where the controller name is supposed to go.

I feel like my brain took off for a vacation on this one =(

Comment: What makes you think it does not work? If your enter `http://<your site>/s` it will take you to the `Index` method of the `Structures` controller. If not, the problem may be the order of your routes

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's exactly what I though too!  Alas, I get "The resource cannot be found." error so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @StephenMuecke AARRRGG, never mind.  I had the "Default" route registered, I guess I didn't know this overwrote all the custom routes.  I commented it out and it worked.

So frustrating...

Comment: That's what I meant by the order of the routes (the order is significant) - you need to put this one before the default route

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh, ok.  So order does mean something with this setup?  I did not know that, thanks for the help.  Drop it as an answer and I'll give you the kudos for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route will work as expected. If not, its probably due the order in which you define your routes (the order is significant).  From [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

> Incoming URLs are compared to route patters in the order the patterns
>   appear in the route dictionary (that is what we added the route maps
>   to in our RouteConfig.cs file).
>
> The first route which successfully matches a controller, action, and
>   action parameters to either the parameters in the URL or the defaults
>   defined as part of the route map will call into the specified
>   controller and action. This is important, and requires us to think our
>   routes through carefully so that the wrong handler is not called
>   inadvertently.